# Indexing the content from URL in Java (Search Engine)

Tags: java, database

I would like to have some help in creating an index for the content that I saved in my database after crawling the URLs and removing the tags. I have been looking for solutions but couldn't find anything helpful yet. The thing is our instructor told us to not use Apache Lucene. I have no idea how to implement this and would like to get help in understanding this better.

Comment: The best place to get started is probably by asking your instructor. The question in its current form allows for too many assumptions or uncertainties about the actual topic and therefore may not produce answers that tackle your actual issue

Comment: we are supposed to start indexing then discuss it later. But I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: Your question unfortunately lacks any information what you want to index or what kind of index you actually need. Do you want to build an inverted index of certain words for easier lookup or just add an index to your tables/collections inside your database?

Comment: I want to build an inverted index based on the content that I have in my database. It should take the words from the content.